# How do you calculate the sum of only the first three numbers in a list in Python?

Tags: python

Eg: list = 1, 2, 3… 10

I am trying to solve a question in my course in as simple a way as possible. 
Sorry if there is already an answer to this question. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hm, `list[0] + list[1] + list[2]`?

Comment: If you are adding using loops, use three iterations only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use slicing:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = sum(mylist[:3])
```

Here, you can easily change `3` to some other number.

See:

- [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)
- [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 2):

if `a` is the `list` the you can do:

```
print sum(a[:3])
```

You can go through the [sum()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum) function of python.

Moreover, `a[:3]` is a [slicing](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice) operation.

Answer (score 0):

The [sum function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) sums numbers in an iterable and is built into Python.

Thus for your situation you can just slice the list and use it.

```
 numbers = [2.5, 3, 4, -5]

    numbersSum = sum(numbers[:3])
    print(numbersSum)
```

result is `2.5+3+4=9.5`